# Solve $\log_2(x+1)=⌊\log_2(x)⌋+1$ in positive integers

Tags: diophantine-equations

This question is related to: [Find all positive integer solutions verifying two conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484134/find-all-positive-integer-solutions-verifying-two-conditions)

Let us consider the following equation:
$$\log_2(x+1)=⌊\log_2(x)⌋+1$$
$\log_2$ is the logarithm in base $2$ (https://www.vedantu.com/maths/log-base-2) and $⌊.⌋$ is the integer part.
I am asking on how one can **find all the integer solutions** $x$. One solution is when $x=3$. Probably, the equation has no solutions for some $x>a$ with $a$ is a given constant.

Comment: Well, note that the conditions require $\log_2(x+1)\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lulu: Yes. It is.

Comment: Which means....

Comment: that $(x+1)^2$ is a multiple of $2$

Comment: No, that's not what it means.

Comment: If $\log_2(x+1) \in \mathbb{Z}, x+1=2^y,$ which $y$ is an integer. It doesn't only means that $x+1$ is a square of 2. Take $y=-1$ for example. (It means that $x+1$ doesn't have to be an integer.)

Comment: Note that $x\geq 1$ implies that $⌊\log_2(x)⌋ +1\geq 1$. This implies that $x=2^y-1$ for some positive integer $y$. Plugging this back into the equation, you get $y=(y-1)+1$. Hence, the set of all positive integers of the form $2^y-1$ is the desired solution.

Comment: How is 3 a solution?

Comment: @MathAndPhysics $\log_2(3+1) = \log_24 = 2$; $\lfloor\log_23\rfloor+1 = \lfloor1.58\ldots\rfloor+1 = 2$.

Comment: Oh okay thank you.

Comment: Why did you post this question here without any thoughts of your own, when the answer is completely obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

$$\log_2(x+1)=⌊\log_2(x)⌋+1\tag 1$$
the right side is an integer, thus $x+1$ must be an integer power of $2$.  Hence $x+1=2^n$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$. In addition, we have that $x$ must be positive (otherwise the $\log$ on the right side is not defined):

$$x=2^n-1 > 0 \iff x+1= 2^n > 1 \implies n > 0 = \log_2 1 $$
so that $n\geqslant1$.

To see that all such $x=2^n-1$ are solutions of $(1)$, observe that $1+⌊\log_B m⌋$ is the number of digits needed to represent $m\in\Bbb N$ in base $B$. In base $2$, $x$ has the representation

$$x=2^n-1 = \underbrace{1\cdots1}_{n\text{ times}}\tag 2$$

so that $⌊\log_2 x⌋+1 = n$.  On the other hand we have that $\log_2 (x+1) = \log_2(2^n) = n$ and $(1)$ holds for all $x=2^n-1$ with $n\in\Bbb N$.

---

A more rigoros treatment of the right-hand side of $(1)$ follows:  As $\log_2$ is strictly increasing, we have

$$\log_2 x = \log_2(2^n-1) < \log_2(2^n) = n \tag 3$$

so that $\log_2 x$ is strictly smaller than integer $n$ and hence $⌊\log_2 x⌋<n$. On the other hand:

$$\log_2 x = \log_2(2^n-1) \geqslant \log_2(2^{n-1}) = n-1 \tag4$$
where the inequality holds due to $2^n-1\geqslant 2^{n-1}$ as $n\geqslant1$. Equation $(4)$ therefore implies $⌊\log_2 x⌋\geqslant n-1$.  Taking the two estimates together:

$$n-1\leqslant ⌊\log_2 x⌋ < n \implies ⌊\log_2 x⌋ =n-1 \implies 1 +⌊\log_2 x⌋ = n$$
so that the RHS and the LHS of $(1)$ are equal to $n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

---

Oops, I just saw that you are looking only for positive integer solutions anyway, so some of the reasoning from above can be omitted.

Comment: -1 Please be aware of the [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Would you explain why my answer is wrong or incomprehensible?

Comment: I haven't read your answer. You are answering a question of extremely low quality, that includes no effort, no context, and has a very trivial answer. This is against site policy, see the link in my previous comment.